# Is the Content-Type header field valid without an encoding?

Tags: http

According to the HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2 standards, would `text/html; charset=utf-8` be a valid value for `Content-Type` without the `charset=utf-8` part?

Answer (score 0):

What's relevant are neither HTTP/1.1 nor HTTP/2, but the definition of the "text/html" internet media type in the HTML5 spec.

And yes, leaving out the charset is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Julian said: The `Content-Type` header as per [RFC 7231, sec. 3.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) is supposed to contain a media type out of the [IANA media type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). Any parameters attached to the media types are subject to the respective registrations. For `text/html` we [find](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html):

> Required parameters : No required parameters

Now the `charset` parameter is a bit special in that it is often implied. But some media types simply do not have one. E.g. all types matching `application/*` are supposed to be binary and thus carry no `charset` parameter. An infamous case is [`application/json`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json):

> Note:  No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration. Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.

Through [RFC 7540, sec. 8.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2), the above also holds true for HTTP/2. In conclusion, syntactically that header is *always* valid without encoding. If it really *is* required is up to the registration of the media type.